# Eclipse Swing Application: UI Forms should display in Locale Language

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I am new to Eclipse and Swing Applications.

My problem is i am Developing an Swing Application where complete GUI should be regional Language ( Hindi OR Telugu). In labels if i type in regional Language, they are not showing in GUI forms. It displays as boxes.

I do not want to support Multi language. Just single language is fine for me. ( App Development is in English but the GUI Labels will be in Telugu (regional language).

I have searched everywhere before i come here. Please help me, how to proceed.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things you need to make sure:

The font you are using should support the language of your choice or else there is no way it would display whatever you have typed in a proper manner. If you find squares in place of text you have typed in then the font you are using does not support the specific language of your choice. Search for the font that supports your specific language.

Hindi is supported if you are using **monospaced** font in your GUI element. I believe you are using drag and drop for creating forms. if so, then in the properties of label/button you can change the font to be used. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks for your help. changing font in properties worked for me. Thanks a lot. Currently i cannot upvote your answer as i do not have 15 reputation. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: I have other problem -- I am using Telugu (South Indian ) language. Where characters are not displayed properly .    example: i want to display  " శ్రీ  "  but it displays as two letter word " two letter word  " . Please help. Thanks

Comment: @user3263685 I used to have that problem  with upvoting a week ago as well mate. Glad that I could help.

Comment: @user3263685 The font is displaying telugu characters except for the " శ్రీ "  character I believe? Then it probably means you need another font that supports telugu.